# Scala - how to pass Callback to a method

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka

I am trying to expose Java method via Scala (from Kafka: https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html). 
This is original Java method:

```
public void commitAsync(OffsetCommitCallback callback)
```

How to pass `callback` to a method in Scala? I have something like:

```
 def commitAsync() = {
    consumer.commitAsync(OffsetCommitCallback callback)
  }
```

Thanks.
Bonus points - how would look like a test for it e.g. using MockitoSugar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can handle the callback like this:

```
def commitAsync() = {
   consumer.commitAsync(new OffsetCommitCallback() {
      def onComplete(m: java.util.Map[TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata], e: Exception) {
        //...
      }
   })
}
```

[OffsetCommitCallback](https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/OffsetCommitCallback.html) is an **interface**, ("similar" as **trait** in Scala), so you can init an instance anonymously.

[Here's](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-10/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka010/OffsetRange.scala#L48) is a quick apparition within Spark project.

Comment: Thanks.. Just to understand, we are creating `new OffsetCommitCallback` with a call to a `commitAsync` method?

Comment: It first creates a concrete instance of `OffsetCommitCallback` that you then pass as callback to the `commitAsync`,

Comment: Thank you.. So in this way anyone can call Scala method `commitAsync` which will then on Complete - give back TopicPartition and Offset... How would someone call this Scala method? (with which parameters?)

Comment: It's internal to the commitAsync method. No need to call it directly from client.

Comment: I need to create a 'test case' for this. How do I initiate a 'call' to this method and how to test it? Thanks.